# Orders shipment Status

Tags: order-status, shipment

when order is placed its in Pending status. But when I create shipment for that order status will stay pending.

I tried to clean the order statuses. refresh all indexes. attached is current order statues in my store.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you INVOICE the order? You should do that before you ship.

Pending status generally means it hasn't been paid yet. When you invoice the order, it captures the payment.

Comment: no, i want to automate the process so its will ship and mark order as processing then when invoice it will capture the money and change status to complete.

Comment: AH - well, the status won't change without you invoicing. Magento doesn't like varying from the Order -> invoice -> ship method. If you do it in any other order, it'll be weird.

A plugin like this one might be up your alley - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/complete-shipping-invoice-in-magento-automatically.html